# VirtualBox Ubuntu install error: upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0zaddr

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, puphpet

Recently I started to use PuPHPet(https://puphpet.com) on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. This is a dual-boot laptop together with Windows 10. I can choose the OS I want to use with GRUB2. Now i'm trying to setup my local dev-environment(mainly PHP, NGINX, MySQL, GIT). 
So I configured a nice setup in PuPHPet locally with Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 LTS x64. Download the file and use it on my local dev-folder(/var/www/my-project). I installed VirtualBox and Vagrant, no problems there.

But, when I try to run "Vagrant up" within my folder where I installed my PuPHPet files it starts to run. So far, so good. But then it takes a long time to continue. After that, I get the following message:

> Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
>   Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within the
>   configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.
>
> If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that Vagrant
>   had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors are
>   usually good hints as to what may be wrong.
>
> If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
>   working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
>   problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes. Verify
>   that authentication configurations are also setup properly, as well.
>
> If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
>   the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.

Alright, so ofcourse I started google'ing. I found out that I get more information when I can see the VirtualBox itself when Ubuntu(in VirtualBox, that is)starts. And then I see the following error message:

> [ 6.990017] piix4_smbus 0000:00:07.0: SMBus base address
>   uninitialized - upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0zaddr

[VirtualBox Ubuntu 16.04 error-message](http://i51.photobucket.com/albums/f363/Seltaeb/Ubuntu/ubuntu_vitualbox.png)

After a lot of google'ing, I can't figure out how to can solve my problem. I tried different kinds of Linux, but nothing works. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

PuPHPet boxes were generated against Virtualbox 5.1, which seems to be non-BC with earlier versions. The GUI shows 5.0.x as the latest, but the website virtualbox.org shows 5.1

Upgrade to 5.1 and you'll be set.